# js - variable to take a certain value

Tags: javascript, variables

Why is not the variable i accessible in the last line? Or to be more precise, it takes the value of the last value of i in the iteration +1 (which actually makes sense). What I would like it to take is the same value that it takes in li_hotel[i] when registering with the event.

```
for (var i = 0; i < li_hotel.length; i++) {
    li_hotel[i].addEventListener('click', function(event) {
        document.querySelector('#content > .left').innerHTML = this.innerHTML;
        document.querySelector('#content > .right').innerHTML = i;
    })
};
```

Thank you.

Comment: Perhaps add a snippet to show what the problem is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because by the time that code is hit, the loop is done. You need a closure:

```
for (var i = 0; i < li_hotel.length; i++) {
    (function(i) {
        li_hotel[i].addEventListener('click', function(event) {
            document.querySelector('#content > .left').innerHTML = this.innerHTML;
            document.querySelector('#content > .right').innerHTML = i;
        })
    })(i)
};
```

Comment: Closures! One day I will understand them - Thanks - it works as intended.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another approach, perhaps somewhat unusual: You can build the function from the [`Function()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function) constructor, which allows you to concatenate `i` into the body string.

Warning: Stack Overflow's syntax highlighting is not up to the task.

```js
var li_hotel = document.querySelectorAll('#hotel>li');
for (var i = 0; i < li_hotel.length; i++) {
    var body = '\
        document.querySelector(\'#content > .left\').innerHTML = this.innerHTML;\
        document.querySelector(\'#content > .right\').innerHTML = '+i+';\
    ';
    li_hotel[i].addEventListener('click', new Function('event',body) );
};
```

```html
<ul id="hotel">
    <li>hotel1</li>
    <li>hotel2</li>
    <li>hotel3</li>
</ul>

<div id="content">
    <div class="left"></div>
    <div class="right"></div>
</div>
```

This avoids the overhead of closures.

Comment: Thanks. I need to finally get confident with closures. No escaping:)